# How to loop through an association in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Noob question alert:**

> Scenario

I have two models in my rails application, viz. Name and Nickname.

The associations are:

```
name has_many :nicknames

nickname belongs_to :name
```

Where, migrations are

```
class CreateNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :names do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class CreateNicknames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :nicknames do |t|
      t.integer :name_id
      t.string :nickname
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I have a home controller as

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
def index
    @names = Name.all
  end
end
```

My home index page looks like

```
<% @names.each do |name| %>
    <h3><%= name.name %></h3>
<% end %>
```

which works fine.

> Problem

I want to display all nicknames under a name

Something like

```
<% @names.each do |name| %>
    <h3><%= name.name %></h3>
    <% @name.each do |nickname| %>
        <p><%= nickname.nickname %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I achieve this??? Please help

**Edit: The associations work just fine**

Extract from rails console:

```
irb(main):025:0> Name.first.nicknames.first
  Name Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names"  ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Nickname Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "nicknames".* FROM "nicknames" WHERE "nicknames"."name_id" = $1  ORDER BY "nicknames"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["name_id", 1]]
=> #<Nickname id: 1, name_id: 1, nickname: "somenickname", created_at: "2016-04-03 14:36:15", updated_at: "2016-04-03 14:36:15">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% @names.each do |name| %>
    <h3><%= name.name %></h3>
    <% name.nicknames.each do |nickname| %>
        <p><%= nickname.nickname %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Gives error "undefined method `nicknames' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: change homes controller index to `@names` instead of `@name`

Comment: Sorry for that, fixed earlier

Comment: Extract from Rails console:

irb(main):025:0> Name.first.nicknames.first
  Name Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "names".* FROM "names"  ORDER BY "names"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Nickname Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "nicknames".* FROM "nicknames" WHERE "nicknames"."name_id" = $1  ORDER BY "nicknames"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["name_id", 1]]
=> #<Nickname id: 1, name_id: 1, nickname: "somenickname", created_at: "2016-04-03 14:36:15", updated_at: "2016-04-03 14:36:15">

Comment: The thing is, you cannot directly type "@names,nicknames", rails needs a context, so, the answer can be something similar to "<% @names.'name.id'.nicknames.each do |nickname| %>"

Comment: We aren't typing `@names.nicknames`. We are running `.nicknames` on an instance of `name`. In your console, try this: `Name.first.nicknames`

Comment: Yeah, it works perfectly, so where lies the problem :(

Comment: A thousand apologies, I wrote  <% @name.nicknames.each do |nickname| %>. Thank you kind gentleman

Answer (score 0):

You have named the array

```
 name.nicknames
```

by using the has_many association (name has_many nicknames). So it should be

```
 @name.nickanames.each { |nick| puts nick }
```

Of course, you can expand that into a block.

Answer (score 0):

This controller will help you to load faster the queries, when it gets bigger.

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @names = Name.includes(:nicknames).all
  end
end
```

Html page:

```
<% @names.each do |name| %>
    <h3><%= name.name %></h3>
    <% name.nicknames.each do |nickname| %>
        <p><%= nickname.nickname %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```